# How many atoms does it take for us to perceive colour?

Tags: optics, visible-light, atomic-physics, vision

Atoms individually have no colors, but when there is a large collection of atoms we see objects colorful, which leads to a question: at least how many atoms are required for us to see the color?

Comment: Are you asking about the perception of colour by the eye when the light comes directly from a source?

Comment: Interesting question, not so clear, but the answers below show that it is worth asking. You should ask yourself what you mean by "color". Color is not an intrinsic property of anything, it is a visual property, something that happens, an event. In the case you are pointing at, you cannot ignore the light factor, "how many atoms" is not a sufficient condition to ask what you are asking. Keep in mind that "atoms" (or molecules) can emit and/or reflect light.

Comment: Why do you say atoms have no colours?

Comment: I don't think that *is* what the question is going for, actually. I think it's about the fact that most materials show colors that depend on their structure at scales *above the size of an atom*. You can look at the spectra of individual atoms, but unless they're metal atoms that's probably not going to tell you much.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08020 single atom single photon scattering.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a question for the Biology stack exchange not the Physics stack exchange since it is about perception of colour.

Comment: Single atom **do** have color. For a single hydrogen or hydrogen-like atom it’s wavelength (color) obeys Bohr’s quantization principle: $nλ=2πr$. Color of objects are perceived from emission or reflection (scattering) of photons by it’s atoms. A single atom can do that. Though our eyes may not perceive a light beam with a single photon intensity.

Comment: @J.Manuel: As others have already said, we should not confuse the human perception of colour with intrinsic properties of atoms. Also, a single atom undergoing photonic emission can only emit one photon at one time, and hence we can't say that the emitted photons have 'colour' corresponding to the atom's emission spectrum. For instance, the pink colour of a hydrogen gas discharge lamp does not correspond to a single wavelength, and we need multiple atoms emitting photons of different wavelengths in roughly the same place and time so that we can perceive the overall 'colour'.

Comment: @J.Manuel: It may be theoretically possible to bombard a single atom with electrons fast enough to make its emitted light visible, but I'm not sure if it ever has been done before.

Comment: @user21820 I fully agree with you. That comment is not intended to be a full answer, that's why I didn't put it as such. It is just a cautionary argument informing the OP that one cannot cathegorically affirm that “atoms individually have no color”. Since, if one considers that for a thing to have color, it just need to send light (photons) into our eyes (by a process of some sort), then atoms individually can do that, even if such a color is not necessarily one found in a rainbow

Answer (score 68):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. A pink (#FF00FF) object appears pink not because each atom is pink (there is no wavelength of light that is perceived to be the same pink by the ordinary human eye. What is happening is that a pink object is emitting (or reflecting) light of multiple wavelengths that enter the eye and are detected and processed to allow us to perceive its colour as pink. One single atom, therefore, would not be able to appear to us as pink under ordinary conditions because it will not emit photons of the appropriate wavelengths rapidly enough that we see no oscillation but a steady pink.
2. Even for colours that correspond to a single wavelength of light, we would need a significant number of atoms before it emits enough photons to form a stable statistical distribution of wavelengths (called an emission spectrum), which we can then perceive and compare to the colours that we have previously experienced. How many atoms are needed would of course depend on the rate of emission, which is proportional to the power output. For reflection it would depend largely on the intensity of light incident on the object.
3. And of course, molecules, complexes and macromolecular structures can have very different spectra compared to their individual constituent atoms, because the energy levels for electrons change drastically when bonds are formed (or broken). For example aqueous $Fe^{3+}$ is yellow while aqueous $Fe^{2+}$ is green, while solid $Fe_2O_3$ is reddish-brown.
4. Only about 10% of the light incident on the eye actually makes it through to the retina. Even those that strike the retina may not be detected.
5. A human eye has receptors called cones and rods. Incidentally, [a rod **can** actually respond to a single photon](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/see_a_photon.html) that strikes an active molecule in it, ultimately triggering an electrical pulse down the optic nerve. A cone is theoretically [able to respond to a single photon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoreceptor_cell#Signal_transduction_pathway) as well, but for the below reason a single photon is never enough for us to see its 'colour'.
6. Each cone absorbs incident photons of different frequencies with different probabilities. This is precisely how we can see many colours using only 3 types of cones, because light of different wavelengths can be distinguished by how much they are absorbed by each type of cone.

   [image] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1416_Color_Sensitivity.jpg)

   But since a photon can only be absorbed by a single cone, it also implies that the retina plus brain needs many photons from the same source before it can get a statistical picture of absorption by the 3 types of cones, which it then interprets as a colour. This is the main reason we need thousands of photons from a point source before we can clearly distinguish its colour from that of other objects. The lower the intensity of light, the harder it is for us to distinguish colours. And note that we perceive the combination of pure red and pure green light (namely the combination of light of two different frequencies) the same way we perceive pure yellow light (of the appropriate single frequency), because they result in the same absorption profile for the three types of cones.
7. Rods are much denser than cones, except in the [fovea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fovea_centralis) where there are nearly no rods, and hence one can see better around the central spot when in the dark. In the fovea, the 'Blue'-sensitive cones (S cones) are also [rarer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell#Structure) than the other two types at about 5%, whereas the 'Red'-sensitive cones (L cones) number about 50% to 75%.

The net effect is that you need something like 100,000 photons from the same point incident on your eye before you can perceive its colour at [the normal human accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#Tolerance), even more for blue light.

And finally there is [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) in the Earth's atmosphere, which scatters 'violet' light (400nm wavelength) about $7$ times as strongly as red light (650nm wavelength).

Comment: The notion of a "statistical picture" of the light absorption by the cones is very nice. Well said!

Comment: You miss some important point about color vision. The 19th Century theory of trichromacy is not sufficient to explain color vision in detail: the real detector is in the brain. Even without much S cones in the fovea, and after blue filtration, we can still clearly see blue in the center of the visual field. More importantly, it is possible to see the color blue in absence of blue light, as shown by experiments by Edwin Land in the 1950's (see: http://www.millenuvole.org/f/Fotografia/Per-quali-ragioni-vediamo-i-colori/edwin_land_1959.pdf ). If we work on dot-shaped light sources in the dark...

Comment: ...standard colorimetric rules apply, trichromacy is fully valid. So here it works.

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com: Yes that's why I was careful not to say anything about the way we interpret colour, hence I said "retina plus brain" instead of trying to expand further. No matter how the retina plus brain does it, they basically have only the statistical absorption levels of the three cone types to infer everything else. I indeed knew of [colour constancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_constancy), which is what you're describing; you can actually try out the images on the Wikipedia article yourself! Anyway thanks for the link! =)

Comment: you should read the article, it will blow your mind. Land was able to reproduce all hues with two slightly different yellow monochromatic light sources at 579 & 599nm, i.e. zero stimulation of the S cones. If you have an explanation for this, let me know.

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com: I read the article. It's explained by colour constancy, which as I said is due to both the retina and the brain. Basically they attempt to identify colours relatively, not absolutely. 2 wavelengths suffice to distinguish colours relatively, but not identify them absolutely. The fact that the red-white image on the Wikipedia article works quite well even using RGB channels (which means they cannot distinguish #ff00ff from #ffff00, unlike using 2-wavelength projections) provides evidence for this claim that we perceive relative and not absolute colour differences.

Comment: Excellent answer above.. I talked to my college grad daughter, who of course knows more than me and she said that this is related to animals that see better in the dark not being able to discern color as well. This makes sense to me as it seems that the trade off of receiving more photons with a similar number of cones would be a lesser ability to separate the wavelengths in the brain.

Comment: @JackR.Woods: Actually, the ability to see in the dark has little to do with colour vision. For example cats have a reflective coating behind the retina called the [tapetum lucidum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapetum_lucidum) that increases ability to see in the dark but sacrifices resolving power. Curiously, human tetrachromats may have better vision in the dark than ordinary humans (trichromats); see [this article](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20140905-the-women-with-super-human-vision).

Comment: Is this also why you have red/green color blindness? I notice that the red and green spectra overlap a lot, so I would imagine that distinguishing between red and green is a much more difficult task than distinguishing either from blue.

Comment: @bob: The overlap has nothing to do with [red-green colour blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Red-green_color_blindness), which has a number of variants all arising from a defective gene for the red or green photoreceptor. In fact, the similar absorption spectrum for red and green photoreceptors makes it **easier to distinguish** wavelengths in the red to green range! This is because a change in wavelength in that range results in a significant and robust change in the relative response of the red or green photoreceptor, namely the weaker/stronger ratio changes a lot.

Answer (score 12):

It depends what you mean by "see". In a [diffraction grating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating), even one photon will fall in the band of the "color" its frequency/energy assigns it.

A large ensemble of photons is necessary for "seeing" light which is described by classical electrodynamics. You can get an idea for how many photons are necessary to act like classical electromagnetism, from this [double slit experiment one photon at a time](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/):

[image: dblsit singlephoton]

> Single-photon camera recording of photons from a double slit illuminated by very weak laser light. Left to right: single frame, superposition of 200, 1’000, and 500’000 frames.

The single frame has maybe 50 photons; by 200 frames, the interference pattern starts to appear. So I would answer that, by 10000 photons, the color should be visible through the [complicated optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision) of the retina of the eye.

Edit after down vote.

Please note that the title of the question was drastically edited after I answered. There exists an answer with perception. This covers the detection of photons.

Comment: I think that the question is about the number of atoms needed to produce sufficient photons to stimulating the cones in the eye to produce the sensation of colour. Difficulties in answering this question include the fact that most sources tend not produce light just in one direction and to register a non-primary colour a number of cones need to be receiving photons from the source.

Comment: If it is 50 _(approx)_ photons per frame, would it not be 10,000 photons in the second image (then 50,000 and then 25,000,000)?

Comment: @Baldrickk  You are correct, I thought that the first on the left  was 200 frames  :( . I will edit. thanks

Comment: Not related to color, but interesting: once the rods in our eyes are suitably adapted, they are sensitive to as few as 6 photons!

Answer (score 9):

To see the color of a piece of matter requires (1) a light source, and (2) a piece of matter. Third case (3) the atoms themsleves can be the light source.
Your question is therefore not well formulated. You wont see any color if there's no light.

It seems first to fall down to the question: *how many photons are required on a certain zone of the retina to produce a color stimulus?*

To observe what you are thinking of with the naked eye in a dark room, you need :

- either a piece of matter that is sufficiently big coupled with a beam of light that is sufficiently bright
- or a piece of matter that emits sufficient light by itself to be noticed and seen as having a color

You should know that your results will be different in a dark room and under daylight:

- in a dark room, the light dots that you'll observe will be clearly visible above a certain threshold
- in the daylight, you'll need more light, the surrounding light will "melt" the stimuli

If some physicist here can calculate the power in terms of photons, here's how you could test your question :

Go to Photoshop and create a black picture, now draw some 1x1 pixels dots on it and look at the picture at 100% magnification :

[image: 1 pix dots on Bk]

(look closely there are red, green, blue, magenta dots)

Personally I have a 15 inch 4k screen, it is possible therefore, knowing the screen's resolution and the geometry of its subpixels, to determine the dot size. You can also calculate the number of photons emitted by a dot it you know each color's value in terms of radiometric power.

The number of photons hitting your retina will depend on the pixel size, the color of the pixel (the emission spectrum of the pixel with a given RGB color), and your distance to the screen.

What is interesting here is that the answer you are seeking depends on the pixel color:

- it is almost impossible for me to see the Blue pixels unless I get very close from the screen
- the same is true with red and magenta pixels, but I can still see them and their color at a greater (about 2 times more) distance.
- green pixels are much brighter (not because they emit more photons, but more likely because my retina is more sensitive to green), I can still see the dot at +- 8 times the distance, BUT, after a certain threshold, I see only **a monochromatic dot**, not a **green** one.

Now you can see that the answer to your question is more complicated than implied in the way you asked it.

Comment: I think the green/blue brightness discrepancy is partly due to the fact that rods absorb more strongly near the 'green' wavelength, as shown by the response curves, and my answer also explains why after a certain point you can no longer distinguish the colour. (See the experimentally obtained curve at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function.) But I'm not so sure that a 0000FF pixel emits as high intensity of light as an FF0000 pixel. I think they are calibrated to achieve the white point, which has nothing to do with actual luminosity of the primaries.

Comment: @user21820 You are right the RGB powers are calibrated for the white point of the screen, I just wanted to point out the fact that the difference of sensitivity is higher than any radiometric power differences between typical RGB values.

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing the main reason is the rod's absorption profile, but unless we know the actual luminosities of the screen pixels, it's hard to tell if it has significant effect as well.

Comment: @user21820 Rods are saturated very quickly by ambient light, and as far as I know, they do not really cause color perception. Isn't the blue/green brightness difference simply explained by the huge difference in numbers between M and S cones?

Comment: @user21820 well... "explained" is a BIG word, but lets say the blue/green brightness difference is in accordance with the huge difference in numbers between M and S cones.

Comment: @user21820 2nd part of the "explanation": anytime light has a high probability to be absorbed by M cones, it also has a high probability to be absorbed by the L cones. Hence, the light looks brighter. In simplified color vision models luminance is coded by L+M response... You can never isolate L response from M response, except around 700 nm (actually the color sensitivity curves from wikipedia are truncated, cone L sensitivity goes as far as 830 nm)

Comment: The problem is that some website claims that the small number of blue cones is made up for by some boosting effect, but cites no sources, so I didn't want to state too confidently that the numbers are all that matter concerning brightness perception. Indeed, the numbers are much more different than my perception seems to suggest, so I think there are other factors at play. As for rods bleaching and L+M response contributing to brightness, yea I think you may be right, since the experimental curve seems to lie in the middle of the L and M absorption curves.

Comment: @user21820 this is a good source: http://www.cvrl.org/pngimages/ssabance_5.png

Comment: That's a log-plot of the graph in my answer, but how does it explain the brightness thing? I think your explanation is right partly because the Wikipedia article mentions that the experimental brightness curve shifts with colour-blindness in a manner consistent with the proportion and absorption profiles of the cones.

Comment: @user21820 I know, I put it there to show you that the sensitivity goes as far as 830 nm!

Comment: Oh! That's very interesting! Sorry I didn't notice it earlier. Thanks!

Comment: I've wondered about the blue visibility, especially when inconsiderate developers have hard-coded text as blue, which is very hard to seen against a normal black background.  Yet blue LEDs are highly visible, and police cars, snow plows, &c have started using them for high visibility rather than (or in addition to) red.  Probably more of a Biology question, though.

Comment: @jamesqf The peak wavelength of these highly visible blue lies between 440 & 470 nm, and Blue LEDs emit lots of such light, that's why we see them well. Also Blue has a very high chroma, so even if we do not perceive much lightness difference, we do see color difference.

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com: Reasonable, but then I have to wonder why the blue component of an RGB display is so much less visible.  That is, if text (or lines &c) is drawn with blue (0,0,255) it's almost impossible to see - though a lighter blue, say (127,127,255) is easily readable.

Comment: @jamesqf: I have another hypothesis. It is known that it is harder to focus on a blue light source than a red or green one. What I didn't know was that this is not only due to chromatic aberration; the fovea has no 'blue' cones in the very centre (https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/5220s8), and also lies in a yellow-pigmented region called the macula (the pigment absorbs blue light). Moreover, the brain may also filter out what it believes to be due to chromatic aberration. This may explain why I find the 3 primaries on an RGB display to be equally bright in large patches [continued]

Comment: [continued] but not when in solitary dots as shown in this post. (Well green still appears a bit brighter but not much.) In any case we can't compare between #0000FF and #7F7FFF because the latter has twice the power output. But to complicate things even further, there is a strange effect (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz%E2%80%93Kohlrausch_effect) that makes unsaturated RGB colours appear less bright than saturated ones. In particular #FF0000 and #00FF00 and #0000FF  all appear brighter than #008080 and #800080 and #808000 and far brighter than #555555.

Comment: @jamesqf It all depends on the surroundings. Your blue text is easy to read on white screen, hard to see on bk. Luminance ratio is much higher on white...

Comment: @jamesqf the same is true of yellow text on white screen...

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com: The readability of blue on white is because of the contrast - perhaps luminance is the  term?  Same with yellow on white.  But a pure RGB red or green is fairly easy to read on either background, even though it would seem that luminance should be the same for R,G,and B.  Just looking around, the router & cable modem on my desk have blue, green, and orange LEDs, and the blue ones certainly seem brighter/more noticable than the others.  It's a mystery to me...

Comment: @jamesqf the Luminance of a srgb screen's "pure" r, g, b, is really not the same. About 0.07 for blue for ex. Very close to the Black point. 0.83 for Yellow, very close to the white point. Blue, however, being almost non-luminous, is VERY colorful. So if you emit the same luminance of Green & Blue, Green 's much more 'whitish'. Check illumination by your blue LED in a room with white light, you'll see only hue -not brightness- difference where there's blue light.

Answer (score 4):

Colour is a biological/mental phenomenon, not a physical one.

This is nicely illustrated by the colour pink, or, the fact that red light and blue light together make pink light:

[image]

The primary colours of light are red, green, and blue, not because of any physics, but because those are the wavelengths that our eyes happen to be sensitive to.

The response curves for each colour are somewhat wide, as a consequence of that: if yellow light strikes our eyes it stimulates the red receptors a bit and the green receptors a bit. If our eye is stimulated by a red light mixed with a green light, the signals produced by the cells are indistinguishable from yellow. This is how computer monitors trick us into thinking they produce a spectrum.

Pink is not a colour insofar as there is no single wavelength of light that you can meaningfully label "pink" -- it HAS to be a mixture. The reason is that if you had a wavelength in between red and blue, it wouldn't stimulate red and blue receptors in the same way that yellow light does for red and green receptors -- the wavelength in between red and blue is simply green. We perceive the red+blue "colour" not as an interpolation, but as an *entirely new, non-physical hallucination of a "colour" that doesn't really "exist" in the real world.*

As others have pointed out, single atoms *do* have a colour. These give the characteristic spectra of neon lamps, or the absorption spectra of the outer layers of stars. When different atoms are together in a mixture, we see their overall colour as a mixture (brown, perhaps). Or, if the atoms are close enough for their wavefunctions to overlap (i.e. they have a chemical bond), then the characteristic wavelength of the whole collection might change (IIRC, this is why certain metals such as gold have anomalous colours).

Basically, the wavelengths of light are all there in nature. As for colour, it's a product of our minds and our eyes.

Comment: Great answer; good to clear up misconceptions! Any atom or object has a **spectra** of wavelengths that it absorbs/emits, which interacts with our eyes in a particular way that results in us seeing some colour, not because colour is intrinsic to the object, though the spectra is. And some colours cannot be perceived without at least two different wavelengths of light.

Comment: "Pink is not a colour" this is pure nonsense. Of course Pink is a color like Black is a color, etc.

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com: Oh I didn't notice that; he probably meant "pink is not a wavelength", since his very first paragraph says "the colour pink"... Spraff: Yes please amend your answer!

Comment: That’s magenta.  I consider pink to be a desaturqted red, and *is* a spectral color.  You’re talking about “the purple line” so purple is a better name.

Comment: "We perceive the red+blue "colour" not as an interpolation, but as an entirely new, non-physical hallucination of a "colour"".  Sure, pink can be made using 440 and 700nm light, and it does require two frequencies.  But green can be made using only 520nm light.  But in the former case, red and blue cones are stimulated; in the latter, red and green cones.  Are you claiming that red and green stimulation is somehow more hallucinatory and less physical than red and blue stimulation then?  In what objective sense are cone combinations "supposed" to be about single wavelengths?

Comment: I'm saying there's an objective difference between the red+green cone stimulation produced by one wavelength and the same stimulation produced by a mixture of wavelengths, and the latter is a hallucination. (Or rather, *more so*.) The case of green light stimulating red cones as well as green cones is furthermore a different kind of hallucination to red+blue stimulation, since no single wavelength can produce the latter and so it *has* to be a hallucination, whereas various shades of green could be produced by pure wavelengths or mixtures. For pink (and brown etc) there is no such option.

Comment: It's a qualitative, subjective distinction, but the very fact of that shows that it's not a question for physics, which is my original point.

Comment: Ignoring details for a second, we have three cones types.  If two different spectra stimulate these three cone types in equivalent ways, there is no physical way possible for us to perceive the difference; thus, we can form a color theory defining color as the relative stimulation of cones.  Now, it sounds like _you_ are saying that because you want to define color as wavelengths, and relative cone stimulations don't work that way, that physical cones being stimulated is a hallucinatory phenomena.  That makes no sense at all to me; it makes more sense to say you're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: In fact, we're talking about processes that don't even occur in the brain; all of the interesting upfront work regarding "pink" versus "green" is done in the retina.  Is our retina hallucinating?

Comment: I'm trying to point out that the word "colour" has a somewhat confused meaning, precisely because of the things you're pointing out. I call "colour" a biological/mental phenomenon (literally the first line of my original answer) and observe that colour sometimes corresponds to a single wavelength of light, sometimes not, and there are overlap, ambiguity, and equivalence effects to bear in mind.

You're running away with a slip up in language. Take a step back.

Comment: "color" doesn't have a confused meaning; it simply has multiple definitions.  Do this: "color 1. (optics) wavelength 2. (colorimetry) equivalence classes of cone stimulations 3. (psychology) ..." and the confusion disappears.  In your answer you start a paragraph by saying that pink(3) is not a color(1), since there's no color(1) that is pink(3).  Sure.  But when you explain why, you suggest yellow(3) is an average(2) of red(1) and green(1) since there is a yellow(1), but since there's no pink(1), we hallucinate(3) it.  _That_ is confusion, and has nothing to do with how color(2) works.

Answer (score 4):

Each type of atom has a specific [absorption/transmission spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_spectroscopy), as does each specific type of molecule, e.g. a molecule of water which is two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom. The spectrum is which frequencies/wavelengths of light get emitted or absorbed by the molecule and how much of each frequency/wavelength. We interpret different frequencies/wavelengths as different colours.

If you can stimulate a single atom to produce enough light quickly enough, you would be able to see colour (a mixture of all its emission frequencies). So the answer is only a single atom is needed, under the right conditions.

When you have more atoms, each one can emit fewer photons on average to give the same overall intensity. There is the added advantage that the atoms are spread over a wider area, meaning more of your retina can be stimulated at the same time.

The rest of your question is about biology, not physics, i.e. how sensitive is the human eye to light and how much light is needed to be able to see colour? This is the question that everyone else has answered.

Comment: A transmission spectrum isn't the same as a reflectance spectrum. Your answer applies to observing transmitted light. An atom may not scatter at certain angles, in which case you will never see a photon if you're standing in the wrong place.

Comment: As @jiggunjer says. There is transmission, emission and absorption. Incident light that is not absorbed is transmitted. Stimulated atoms or molecular structures can emit light, and the emission and absorption spectra have the same frequencies (because of same energy levels of electron orbitals) but different intensities (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_spectrum#Relation_to_emission_spectrum).

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is ill-posed. Even single atoms can "have a colour" if you define having a colour as emitting photons with a certain frequency. The question should rather be: How many of these photons per time does the human eye need to absorb in order to perceive the corresponding colour? However, this is rather a biological question than a physical one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, individual atoms have color; [Color is different wavelengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color#Physics_of_color) released by the [atom when excited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excited_state). Secondly, to see color you need about 0.1 square millimeters of atoms because this how small the naked eye can see.

Comment: You do not need to "see" the object emitting the photons all you need is enough photons emitted by the object hitting the retina.

Comment: @Farcher: I agree. This is why a star we could not see with naked eye might be visible as a supernova.

Comment: @Krumia: Precisely. This answer is flatly wrong. Resolution power of an optical detector (eyeball or otherwise) has nothing to do with the intensity of incident photons (of a given frequency) that is needed for it to detect a difference from no light.

Comment: This answer lacks logic and physical reality: (1) Color is not "different wavelengths", this is nonsense. Color is a sensation. (2) 0.1 mm² has no visual meaning, can you see a 0.1 mm² object at 10 km distance? Yes, if it is VERY bright...

Comment: The OP asked "how many atoms are required for us to see the color?"; Not how many photons or how bright it's; this's different answer for different question.

Comment: @Hammar we know, however the question itself doesn't make sense, because there are many different combinations of "many atoms" that can be visible or not, colorful or not.

Comment: @Farcher give me one example of a real situation where you do not see the object that directs (whether by emission or reflection) light to your sight.

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com I understand what you are getting at but when a single photon hits a receptor in the retina you will not be "seeing" the object.

Comment: @Farcher if a single photon hits your retina once, you will not see anything. If the flow of photons is strong enough, you'll see the shape of the emitter  immediately.